# moving actors with the gesture listener Libgdx

Tags: libgdx, gesture, actor, gestures, stage

Hello I've been stuck on an issue for a while trying to create a simple game using the Libgdx framework.

I have a stage with a background Image actor and a stick figure image actor that is placed in the center of the stage.

I cant seem to understand, after reading many posts on stackoverflow and the libgdx wiki on event handling, how events such as fling and pan are passed to the actor to simply move it my stickman around the screen.

I would greatly appreciate any help or explanations on how exactly this works.

I just don't know how to get the integer values from pan and the velocity values from fling into my actor's Vector2 position variable so that it can move around every time the render method is called.

Here is some of my code:

My GestureDetection Class:

```
public class GestureDetection implements GestureListener{

    public GestureDetection(){
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean tap(float x, float y, int count, int button) {
        System.out.println("tapped");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean longPress(float x, float y) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean fling(float velocityX, float velocityY, int button) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean pan(float x, float y, float deltaX, float deltaY) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean panStop(float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean zoom(float initialDistance, float distance) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean pinch(Vector2 initialPointer1, Vector2 initialPointer2,
            Vector2 pointer1, Vector2 pointer2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

My Game class

```
public class Game implements Screen{

    StickFlick game;
    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture gameBackground;
    Stage stage;
    GestureDetector gd;
    InputMultiplexer im;
    WalkingEnemy testEnemy;

    public Game(StickFlick game){
        this.game = game;
        testEnemy = new WalkingEnemy("basic", 100, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        //enemy1.update(delta);
        System.out.println("");

        stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());

        batch.begin();
        stage.draw();
        batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        stage = new Stage(width, height, true);
        stage.clear();

        gd = new GestureDetector(new GestureDetection());
        im = new InputMultiplexer(gd, stage);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(im);

        Texture gameBackground = new Texture("data/gameBackground.png");
        Image backgroundImage = new Image(gameBackground);
        backgroundImage.setWidth(Gdx.graphics.getWidth());
        backgroundImage.setHeight(Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        stage.addActor(backgroundImage);

        stage.addActor(testEnemy.getImage());

        stage.addAction(Actions.sequence(Actions.alpha(0), Actions.fadeIn(1)));

    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so at start you have to make some variables where you will keep X and Y coords of your stick man. Set some initial values to them, i.e. x should be half of screen width and y half of screen height to have your stick man at the center of the screen.

Then you have to use information you are getting in your GestureListener implementation to move your stick man, that is to change it's coordinates. Your current implementation does absolutely nothing - methods are empty, so when some gesture happens your code is not reacting to it.

So, you can i.e. inside of your pan method use deltaX and deltaY to change stick man coordinates for those values. Something like:

```
X+=deltaX;
y+=deltaY;
```

Or you can multiply deltaX and deltaY with some constant if you want faster or slower movement and/or multiply deltaY with -1 if movement is in opposite way from what you want it to be.

Or if you want to use fling use those variables that method provides - velocityX and velocityY - add them to you stick man x and y to move it.

So basically, you are always drawing stick man at x,y coords and from some method of GestureListener interface you implemented you should change stick man coords and make him move.

Comment: Thank you, it is really appreciated very much.